# SSH Login from Termius using HashiCorp Vault's Certificate based Authentication on any Linux Server

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, public-key, private-key

Can we able to login to the Linux server with Certificate Based Authentication (which is provided by Hashicorp Vault) through **Termius** ?

**I have a requirement to login through Public key and Private key on any linux server through Termius and simultaneously able to manage the access i.e revoke system n ol using Vault.**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to login to linux server via termius . But the credentials of that Linux server is provided and manage by Vault by SSH Certificate Based Authentication .